# Threading in wpf GUI thread is too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

My application has work to do in background in another thread and the Gui drawing result from list the background thread fill this list

In initialization I made the background thread and when I press button in Gui this thread begin working ; and I click on another buttom to read result while the background thread working but The GUI is very very slow to response to result.

is there any solution I want my results display on GUI faster ?

my code:

```
Thread startdrawingthread = new Thread(StartDrawing);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void bt_draw_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ch_single.IsChecked == true || ch_entire.IsChecked == true)
    {
        currentMode = "";
        startdrawingthread.Start();
        //StartDrawing();
        real_area.DrawingArea.Children.Clear();
        real_area.DrawGrid(20);
    }
}

private void bt_single_next_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (GlobalV.isfinished == false)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (GlobalV.Attatched_Elements.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    real_area.DrawingArea.Children.Clear();
                    real_area.DrawGrid(20);
                    real_area.DrawElement(GlobalV.Attatched_Elements[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                break;
            }
        }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as long as `GlobalV.Attatched_Elements.Count` is zero, your event handler goes through an endless loop of `while (true)`.

I guess that `GlobalV.Attatched_Elements.Count` is set somewhere in `StartDrawing`, but you can not busy-wait like this until it gets greater than zero. You should perhaps remove the whole `if (GlobalV.isfinished == false)` and `while (true)` blocks and simply do the following, which especially does nothing if there is nothing to do:

```
private void bt_single_next_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (GlobalV.Attached_Elements.Count > 0) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

maybe with also [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)ing the collection for thread-safe access:

```
private void bt_single_next_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    lock (GlobalV.Attached_Elements)
    {
        if (GlobalV.Attached_Elements.Count > 0) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You've committed sin #1 in asynchronous programming.

You have a busy loop. Instead of waiting for `GlobalV.Attatched_Elements.Count` to change, you constantly, non-stop ask "is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now? is it nonzero now?", as fast as the CPU can do it.

In other words, you're wasting a lot of execution time.

What you **want** to do is simply subscribe to an event telling you when `Count` changes. Then, when it changes, you check if it is nonzero, and perform the necessary processing.